# Using SqlPackage .NET 6 edition. How to specify Data/Log file paths?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, sqlpackage, dac, bacpac

I am forced to use the .Net 6 version of SqlPackage.exe to import a bacpac file.
I have looked over the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-import?view=sql-server-ver16

But I can't see an option to set the Data file path (for the mdf file) and the Log file path (for the ldf file). In the old version of the tool you could set those values in the UI in the screenshot below.
[image]

Is there a way to specify this values in the command line?